# How to fake a datacontext method with TypeMock Isolator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, typemock, typemock-isolator

I want to test a class that uses Linq to SQL.
I have faked the datacontext with TypeMock Isolator, but the datacontext also has a function that I don't know how to fake.
This function is used in Linq to Sql-queries.

The function passes two arguments (int? a, string b), and returns an integer;
DC.MyMethod(int? a, string b)

How to I fake this?

```
//Fake datacontext
var fakeDC = Isolate.Fake.Instance<MyDataContext>();

//Fake --> this doesn't work
Isolate.WhenCalled((int? a, string b) => fakeDC.MyFunction(a,b).... ?
```

Hope anyone can help

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an error description. What is happening?

Comment: Don't mock it. Abstract it away: http://bit.ly/gHLubu.

Answer (score 3):

Isolator by default ignores arguments passed to functions. To fake yours, you could simply use:

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDC.MyFunction(null, null)).WillReturn(...)
```

If you need to make sure it was called with specific arguments, add `WithExactArguments()`, like this:

```
int? id = 10;
string name = "David";

Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDC.MyFunction(id, name)).WithExactArguments().WillReturn(...);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I get a NullReferenceException with this solution.

Comment: Where exactly? Would you mind sending us a stack trace to support@typemock.com?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I work in Typemock.

To avoid exceptions you should fake all future instatnces of MyDataContext:

```
var fakeDC = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<MyDataContext>();
```

And then set the behavior fo MyFunction():

```
int? id = 10;
string name = "David";

Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDC.MyFunction(id, name)).WithExactArguments().WillReturn(..);
```

It makes sure that all instances of MyDataContext will be faked (created by new MyDataContext() in any part of your program), and MyFunction() behavior will be faked as well.

Since i don't know all the details, check the example below for more understanding:

```
internal class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    public int Bar()
    {
        var x = new MyDataContext();
        return x.MyFunction(null, "5");
    }
}

public class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
   //
    public int MyFunction(int? a, string b)
    {
        if(a == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestMyDataContext()
{
     //Arrange
     var fakeDC = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<MyDataContext>();
     Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeDC.MyFunction(null, "5")).WithExactArguments().WillReturn(6);

     //Act
     var foo = new Foo();
     var res = foo.Bar();

     //Assert
     Assert.AreEqual(6, res);
 }
```

See all information in our [docs](http://www.typemock.com/docs).